# Implementing methods in ByteBuddy to change runtime-discoverable fields

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I am using Byte Buddy to create classes of bean-like interfaces at runtime, reducing tons of boilerplate code. It's trivial to create fields from getters and setters, but I want to leverage Byte Buddy more. For starters, I don't want to have to write code like this all over the place:

```
    if (obj.getMax() < obj.getMin()) {
        int temp = obj.getMax();
        obj.setMax(obj.getMin());
        obj.setMin(temp);
    }

    obj.setMax(obj.getMax() + 1);
    int currentMax = getMax();
```

when I can just do:

```
    obj.enforceMinMaxOrder();
    int currentMax = obj.incrementAndGetMax();
```

Here's an abbreviated example. How can I use Byte Buddy to make the above two work? Presumably using an interceptor class, but I have not come across any examples that modify fields. Important things:

- the fields are not known at compile time, they will be extracted from the method names (i.e. "enforceMinMaxOrder" method name uses "min" and "max" as the field names)
- I'd like to avoid runtime reflection used after Byte Buddy generates the classes, but holding references to fields or methods and invoking those is fine.

  ```
  DynamicType.Builder<? extends Object> builder = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class);
  builder = builder.implement(MyInterface.class);
  builder = builder.method(
      (isGetter().or(isSetter())))
      .intercept(FieldAccessor.ofBeanProperty());
  for (Method m : MyInterface.class.getMethods()) {
      String methodName = m.getName();
      Class<?> t = m.getReturnType();
      if (t != void.class && methodName.startsWith("get")) {
          String fieldName = Character.toLowerCase(methodName.charAt(3)) + methodName.substring(4);
          builder = builder.defineField(fieldName, t, Visibility.PUBLIC);
          builder = builder.method(named(fieldName)).intercept(FieldAccessor.ofField(fieldName));
      }
  }

  MyInterface obj = (MyInterface) builder.make().load(BeanUtil.class.getClassLoader()).getLoaded().getConstructor().newInstance();

  obj.setMin(10);
  obj.setMax(5);

  obj.incrementAndGetMin();
  obj.ensureMinMaxOrder();
  // now, the values should be min=5, max=11
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think your best call would be using `Advice` which let's you write code templates that are later inlined into a generated class:

```
class MinMaxAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodExit
  static void minMax(@Min int min, @Max int max) { ... }
}
```

The method implements your code and can override any field values. Since your resolution is method-name sensitive, you would need to add your own bindings for custom annotations `@Min` and `@Max`, have a look at the `Advice.withCustomBinding()` API to learn how this is done. You can reuse the field bindings that exist already, but you have to locate those fields in the manner you want to achieve this.